# String into a multi-dimensional array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

Really newb question, sorry.
I have a string like this made up of several words and want to turn it into an array where each word is a sub array within an array.

```
my_string = "Made up of several words"
my_array = []
my_string.split(/\s/) do |word|
  my_array << word
end
```

gives me

```
["Made", "up", "of", "several", "words"]
```

but I want to get:

```
[["Made"], ["up"], ["of"], ["several"], ["words"]]
```

Anyone know how I can do this please?  I'm using the do end syntax because I want a code block where next I can add some logic around what I do with certain words coming in from the string. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
my_string = "Made up of several words"
my_array = my_string.split(/\s+/).map do |word|
  [word]
end
# => [["Made"], ["up"], ["of"], ["several"], ["words"]]
```

Comment: That was the trick.  Putting [ ] around the variable made it come through as an ARRAY as I needed.  Thanks

Comment: If `my_string` were `"Made up    of several words"` you would get `=> [["Made"], ["up"], [""], [""], [""], ["of"], ["several"], ["words"]]`.  Rather than `split(/\s/)`,I think it would be better to just use `split` without an argument, which is the same as `split(' ')`, which disregards extra whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

How about below :

```
my_string = "Made up of several words"
my_string.scan(/(\w+)/) 
# => [["Made"], ["up"], ["of"], ["several"], ["words"]]
```